# I cannot change the value of my object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

GameManager.js

```
export class Game {
  constructor(score, faction) {
    this.score = score;
    this.faction = faction;
  }
}

export const game = new Game(0, null);
```

GameSettings.js

```
import { game } from "./GameManager.js";

const faction_aco = document.getElementById("aco");
const faction_fun = document.getElementById("fun");

faction_aco.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Your Faction is APOCALYPSE");
  game.faction = "AI_APOCALYPSE";
  localStorage.setItem("Faction", game.faction);
  console.log(game);
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.replace(baseUrl + "/desktop.html");
  }, 3000);
});
faction_fun.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Your Faction is FUNDAMENTAL");
  game.faction = "AI_FUNDAMENTAL";
  localStorage.setItem("Faction", game.faction);
  window.location.replace(baseUrl + "/desktop.html");
});
```

Desktop.js

```
import { game } from "./GameManager.js";

console.log(game);
```

I created a game object within the GameManager file. In the GameSettings file, I'm using addEventListener to change the value of the 'faction' property inside it. However, when I call the game object again in the Desktop.js file within the GameManager, it still shows 'faction: null' in the console.

Comment: Well the values aren't going to change until those "click" handlers are called, and your "Desktop" script simply logs the value of the Game object once, when it loads.

Comment: You're only writing to `localStorage` but never reading from it.

Comment: When you `window.location.replace` the `export const game = new Game(0, null);` is executed (browsers don't remember javascript from a previous url) - perhaps you need to read localStorage? `export const game = new Game(0, localStorage.getItem("Faction"));` could work